# How to use single thread class for multiple web calls in android

Tags: android

I've two buttons. I need to get two different web calls using two buttons. But need to use single thread through. If I use like below code, the thread class didn't return `json` response. It returns `null` value. How could I resolve this issue?

MY Thread class:

```
public static json runDialogLogin(String URL) {

    JSONObject json;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // getting JSON string from URL
                json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }.start();
    return json;
}
```

My Main class:

.....

```
@Override
public final void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            json= runDialogLogin("My URL1");
            if(json!=null){
                Intent i=new Intent(this,result1.class);
                startActivity(i);

                case R.id.button2:
                json= runDialogLogin("My URL2");
                if(json!=null){
                    Intent i=new Intent(this,result2.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is strangely designed :

```
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
```

and

```
    return json;
```

don't use the same json object, they just share a name but are not the same variable. The first one has a scope limited to your run method. You can't get a reference on it outside this scope.

Comment: ....
  new Thread() {
   public void run() {

    try {

       JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
     intent=i;

    } catch (Exception e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

  }.start();
  return intent;
 }  Is it correct?

Comment: How can you return a value for something that will be built during a different thread execution ? Look at async task and stop using threads this way.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a `thread` and immediately returning the result from the thread. Wait till the response comes from the server and then return it.

Code should be like

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

            // wait till you get the response from the server and then return the json object here only.
            return json;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: @kamerwari if i use return statement like u said means.,it asks me to set like public json run() {..Again if i do so.,it shows error at method name called runDialogLogin() to give return stmt.What can i do for that?